# JFrame (Swing) update(graphics) error

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

I have a little game with little Rect, which are moving and I need to update the `Graphics` by doing `this.update(MyGraphics)` in my `onUpdate` method, which gets called every 50 millisekonds. But when I do this `this.update(MyGraphics)` all my `buttons` and `textfields` are glitched.

Does somebody have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the examples how to update `JPanel` by a timer.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainClass extends JPanel {

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Oval Sample");
    static MainClass panel = new MainClass(Color.CYAN);
    static Color colors[] = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW};
    static Color color;
    static int step = 0;

    public MainClass(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    final static Timer tiempo = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//            paintComponent();
            System.out.println("Step: " + step++);
            if (step % 2 == 0) {
                color = Color.DARK_GRAY;
            } else {
                color = Color.BLUE;
            }
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        panel = new MainClass(colors[2]);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        tiempo.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be overriding `paintComponent(...)`.

Comment: This is not working, because the Paint method only updates when i click on the next Round button//I interact with the Jpanel but i want it to update without me doing anything

Answer (score 0):

> when I do this this.update(MyGraphics) all my buttons and textfields are glitched.

Don't invoke `update(...)` directly. That is not the way custom painting is done.

Instead when you do custom painting you override the `paintComponent(...)` method of the JPanel:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //  add your custom painting here
}
```

> I have a little game with little Rect, which are moving

If you want animation then you should use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation. Then when the Timer fires you invoke a method on your custom class to change the location of the rectangle and then you invoke `repaint()`. This will cause the panel to be repainted.

Read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on:

1. Performing Custom Painting
2. How to Use Swing Timers

to get your started with basic examples.